# Installing Oracle JDK 1.7 -- 404 error

Tags: apt, software-installation, java, jdk, hadoop

I'm trying to install Hadoop 2.7.3. on Elementary OS (which ~ Ubuntu, I believe) following the instructions in the *BUILDING.txt* that came with the Hadoop files.

The file indicates that I need to install Oracle JDK 1.7 by going through the following steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

All works well until the last step, where it exits with an error message which I'm not sure what to make of (sorry if paste is too long; I'd be happy to edit it but Idk what's relevant):

```
--2017-05-26 10:58:06--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-
b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz Resolving download.oracle.com
(download.oracle.com)... 199.117.103.169, 199.117.103.171

Connecting to download.oracle.com
(download.oracle.com)|199.117.103.169|:80... connected. HTTP request
sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily Location:
https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

[...]

```
[following]

--2017-05-26 10:58:06--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1495814405_54d4699c133b9ceee2666c152616ece6
Connecting to download.oracle.com
(download.oracle.com)|199.117.103.169|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2017-05-26
10:58:07 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed

Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure): 
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
oracle-jdk7-installer:  oracle-jdk7-installer depends on
oracle-java7-installer; however:   Package oracle-java7-installer is
not configured yet.
```

I figured

- the 404 is the main issue - it's looking for files but can't find them

So my question is

- Is that even true? What is the roadblock here?
- How can I fix it, or do I have to take another path?

(I am following White's *Hadoop - The Definitive Guide* for the overall approach. )

Comment: It looks like Oracle moved the location of the JDK: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4048619

Comment: What would be the solution to this?

Comment: @nhaarman there are [other methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) described on askubuntu. I just ended up downloading the installer from the [Oracle Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) for which you need to set up a free account first. Then installed by hand.

Comment: @patrick, you could self-answer with the above information.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Jeff Schaller, moving my comment into the answer:
There are [other methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) described on askubuntu. I just ended up downloading the installer from the [Oracle Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) for which you need to set up a free account first. Then installed by hand.